# How can I limit the number of loops in a Do While loop?

Tags: excel, vba, do-loops

So I've written a function that that uses text-box inputs to search for corresponding values in another sheet. The problem is if it doesn't find a match it goes into an infinite loop. Can I limit the loops so it doesn't crash?
If there is another solution rather than limiting loops, I'm all ears.
Here's what I'm working with:

```
Function Most_Recent_Deployment(Label1 As String, Label2 As String, Label3 As String) As Long
    Dim all_rows As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
    Set LastCell = Sheet7.Cells(Sheet7.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).End(xlUp)
    LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.row + 1
    Set row = Sheet7.Range("A:A").Find(Label1, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=Cells(LastCellRowNumber, "A"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Do While row.row > 1

        If (Sheet7.Cells(row.row, 2).Text = Label2) And (Sheet7.Cells(row.row, 3).Text = Label3) Then
            Most_Recent_Deployment = row.row
            Exit Function
        End If
        LastCellRowNumber = row.row
        Set row = Sheet7.Range("A:A").Find(Label1, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=Cells(LastCellRowNumber, "A"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    Loop
    Most_Recent_Deployment = 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an 'AND' piece to your 'Do While' loop with a counter inside the loop that will indicate when you have reached the end of data in your spreadsheet.

Something like:

```
dim counter as integer    
Do While row.row > 1 and counter > worksheetfunction.counta(sheet7.range("A:A")

    If (Sheet7.Cells(row.row, 2).Text = Label2) And (Sheet7.Cells(row.row, 3).Text = Label3) Then
        Most_Recent_Deployment = row.row
        Exit Function
    End If
    LastCellRowNumber = row.row
    Set row = Sheet7.Range("A:A").Find(Label1, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=Cells(LastCellRowNumber, "A"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    coutner=counter+1

Loop
```

I mean, yes, it's a bit basic, but I think think that it will do the job you're looking for without having to change your code too much. Hope it helps.

Edit:

```
LastCellRowNumber=row.row
temp2=temp1
temp1=LastCellRowNumber

Set row = Sheet7.Range("A:A").Find(Label1, LookIn:=xlValues, After:=Cells(LastCellRowNumber, "A"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

if row.row=temp1 and temp1=temp2 then
    exit do
end if
```

Comment: I feel like its so close, the problems is now it doesn't go into the if at all.

Comment: was it going to the if before? Also, forgot to mention this in my answer, but you may want to change 'Exit Function' to 'Exit Do' so it doesn't skip that last bit you have outside of the loop.

Comment: yes it was, if row.row >1 because its searching through rows from the bottom, once it gets to one it should stop. But it never gets there! I need it to exit function because that means it has found a match. This function is being called elsewhere and uses row to find the row number of the most recent occurrence of a certain label1, label2, label3.

Comment: So, what it looks like is happening to me is that the value of `row.row` never reaches 1 because it's value is based on `.find`. If the object that it is looking for is not in the first row, then the code begins in it's infinite loop. You could put a condition in your original code that will check to see if the value of the previous  `LastCellRowNumber` is the same as the new one and then exiting the loop if that is the case.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what's happening. Any suggestions as to how I'd accomplish this?

Comment: Please ignore that previous comment. I edited my answer. Try putting that in your loop where you change the value of `LastCellRowNumber` (I used 2 temp variable to see if the past 3 instances are the same).

Answer (score 0):

You might try Do Until. eg:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) 
    ' Store the current cell value in the dCellValues array
    dCellValues(iRow) = Cells(iRow, 1).Value
    iRow = iRow + 1 
Loop
```

Code from [ExcelFunctions.net](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Loops.html).

Comment: I'm quite new to VBA so I wouldn't be sure how to do this. I'd like to avoid rewriting a large portion of this code if possible. Thank you